# PhpStorm: Define that method used as callback is being used

Tags: php, phpstorm

Does anyone knows how to define that a method, included as a callback in a `array_map`, is being used?

Is there any comment that can be used to PhpStorm notice this?

```
private static function formatCats($string)
{
    $cats = array_map(
        'self::formatCatValue',
        Dummy::dummyMethod($string)
    );

    return $cats;
}

private static function formatCatValue($string)
{
    return str_replace(array(' ', '.', ',', '-'), '', $string);
}
```

Comment: Please put the actual code in your question.  An image link is not acceptable for numerous reasons (It's not accessible or searchable, the question will be useless if the image ceases to be available, etc)

Comment: @GordonM thanks. Updated.

Comment: There's no such a way. The only thing you can do is suppressing the inspection for the statement.